# Could we use DNS round robin with nscd's dns cache?

Tags: domain-name-system, load-balancing, glibc

I try to use DNS round robin with nscd's dns cache.

But I am not convinced about the belows.

1. nscd respect the dns record ttl at its dns reply
2. the traffic from clients with nscd are distributed equally to servers behind domain name

Is it possible to use DNS round robin with nscd?

Comment: I try to move my post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73181902/could-we-use-dns-round-robin-with-nscds-dns-cache) but I had lower reputations so I cannot answer my question.